# How do I get the balance of an account (on a given day) using the Quickbooks SDK?

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I'd like to query for an account balance as of a given day.

It looks like I could probably do this using the CustomDetailReportQuery, but seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how is to use the CustomDetailReportQuery and set the appropriate dates, and look for the Total Row.

```
public bool GetBalance(string sAccount, DateTime dt, out decimal balance)
{
    balance = 0.0M;

    IMsgSetRequest msr = sm.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 7, 0);
    msr.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

    ICustomDetailReportQuery q = msr.AppendCustomDetailReportQueryRq();
    q.ReportOpenBalanceAsOf.SetValue(ENReportOpenBalanceAsOf.robaoReportEndDate);
    q.DisplayReport.SetValue(false);
    q.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icDate);
    q.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icName);
    q.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icMemo);
    q.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icDebit);
    q.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icCredit);
    q.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icRunningBalance);
    q.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.ToReportDate.SetValue(dt);
    q.ReportAccountFilter.ORReportAccountFilter.FullNameList.Add(sAccount);

    q.CustomDetailReportType.SetValue(ENCustomDetailReportType.cdrtCustomTxnDetail);
    q.SummarizeRowsBy.SetValue(ENSummarizeRowsBy.srbTotalOnly);

    IMsgSetResponse msrgrsp = sm.DoRequests(msr);
    try
    {
        if (msrgrsp.ResponseList.Count == 1)
        {
            IResponse resp = msrgrsp.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
            if (resp.StatusCode == 0)
            {
                IReportRet rp = (IReportRet)resp.Detail;
                IORReportData data = rp.ReportData.ORReportDataList.GetAt(rp.NumRows.GetValue() - 1);
                if (data.TotalRow != null)
                {
                    balance = decimal.Parse(data.TotalRow.ColDataList.GetAt(data.TotalRow.ColDataList.Count - 1).value.GetValue());
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log("Error finding balance of " + sAccount + ":");
        Log(e.Message);
    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do a [CustomSummaryReportQuery](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) This will return the minimal data desired.

Most of the code is standard but use this for building the query and walking through the report returned. Leave QBCustName blank to get all customers. The customer balances will be returned as of the end date.

Code is VB.net

```
Imports QBFC7Lib

Private Sub BuildCustomSummaryReportQueryRq(ByVal requestMsgSet As IMsgSetRequest, _
                                            ByVal EndDate As Date, ByVal QBCustName As String)

    Dim CustomSummaryReportQueryRq As ICustomSummaryReportQuery
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomSummaryReportQueryRq()

    'Set field value for CustomSummaryReportType
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.CustomSummaryReportType.SetValue(ENCustomSummaryReportType.csrtCustomSummary)

    'Set field value for DisplayReport
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.DisplayReport.SetValue(False)

    'Set FromReportDate to earliest possible date
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.FromReportDate.SetValue(DateTime.Parse("1/1/1901"))
    'Set field value for ToReportDate
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.ToReportDate.SetValue(EndDate)

    'Set field value for AccountTypeFilter
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReportAccountFilter.ORReportAccountFilter.AccountTypeFilter.SetValue(ENAccountTypeFilter.atfAccountsReceivable)

    'Set field value for EntityTypeFilter
    If QBCustName = "" Then
        'all customers
        CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReportEntityFilter.ORReportEntityFilter.EntityTypeFilter.SetValue(ENEntityTypeFilter.etfCustomer)
    Else
        'limit by customer name
        CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReportEntityFilter.ORReportEntityFilter.FullNameList.Add(QBCustName)
    End If

    'Set field value for ReportDetailLevelFilter
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReportDetailLevelFilter.SetValue(ENReportDetailLevelFilter.rdlfSummaryOnly)

    'Set field value for ReportPostingStatusFilter
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReportPostingStatusFilter.SetValue(ENReportPostingStatusFilter.rpsfEither)

    'Set field value for SummarizeColumnsBy
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.SummarizeColumnsBy.SetValue(ENSummarizeColumnsBy.scbTotalOnly)

    'Set field value for SummarizeRowsBy
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.SummarizeRowsBy.SetValue(ENSummarizeRowsBy.srbCustomer)

    'Set field value for ReportCalendar
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReportCalendar.SetValue(ENReportCalendar.rcCalendarYear)

    'Set field value for ReturnRows
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReturnRows.SetValue(ENReturnRows.rrActiveOnly)

    'Set field value for ReturnColumns
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReturnColumns.SetValue(ENReturnColumns.rcActiveOnly)

    'Set field value for ReportBasis
    CustomSummaryReportQueryRq.ReportBasis.SetValue(ENReportBasis.rbAccrual)
End Sub

'class to hold customer balance
Public Class CustBalReport
    Public QBCustName As String
    Public EndBal As Decimal
End Class

Private Sub WalkReportRetCustom(ByVal ReportRet As IReportRet)

    'new list of customer bal items
    Dim CustBalList As New List(Of CustBalReport)

    'report title
    Dim ReportTitle7 As String = ReportRet.ReportTitle.GetValue()

    'report date
    Dim ReportSubtitle8 As String = ReportRet.ReportSubtitle.GetValue()

    Dim ErrNum As Integer = 1
    Try

        'iterate the report lines
        ErrNum = 2
        For RowNum As Integer = 0 To ReportRet.ReportData.ORReportDataList.Count - 1

            'get new item
            Dim ReportLine As CustBalReport = Nothing
            ReportLine = New CustBalReport

            'get row
            ErrNum = 3
            Dim ORReportData17 As IORReportData = Nothing
            ORReportData17 = ReportRet.ReportData.ORReportDataList.GetAt(RowNum)

            'don't care about total line; only get data rows
            If ORReportData17.ortype = ENORReportData.orrdDataRow Then

                'get customer name
                ErrNum = 5
                Dim ColCustName As IColData = Nothing
                ColCustName = ORReportData17.DataRow.ColDataList.GetAt(0)
                ReportLine.QBCustName = ColCustName.value.GetValue

                'get customer balance
                ErrNum = 6
                Dim ColBalance As IColData = Nothing
                ColBalance = ORReportData17.DataRow.ColDataList.GetAt(1)
                ReportLine.EndBal = ColBalance.value.GetValue

                'add to list
                CustBalList.Add(ReportLine)
            End If

        Next RowNum

        'assign to class variable
        lCustBalList = CustBalList

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errMsg As String = ErrNum & ": Error getting customer balance summary"
        Throw New ApplicationException(errMsg)
    End Try

End Sub
```